# ical sync with basic auth under outlook

Tags: outlook, calendar, icalendar

I've got a problem with ical sync with outlook.
My implementation works with other calendars like macOS, iOS calendars and thunderbird.

Outlook can't seem to find the calendar though.
Whenever I add the calendar in Outlook 2013 or 2010 it suggests that it correctly imported the calendar, doesn't display anything nor does it ask for authentication.
Although the ical file needs Basic Auth.

Any Ideas what Outlook does different or how I could further debug it?

Sample URL:

```
https://domain/caldav/2abd35d3-3b21-479f-85aa-a91598a686db.ics
```

URL for outlook:

```
webcal://domain/caldav/2abd35d3-3b21-479f-85aa-a91598a686db.ics
```

Sample Ical:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//schuchert//factro//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:02427fd7-2003-493e-93be-7f8e2679c478@factro
SEQUENCE:0
DTSTAMP:20170116T110547Z
DTSTART:20150824T063000Z
DTEND:20150824T151500Z
SUMMARY:Refactoring im Frontend
ORGANIZER;CN="marudor":mailto:marudor@marudor.de
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Same here, using Outlook 2016. Just get a 401 in the server logs. No asking for credentials, other clients do.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about authentication itself but found out that for https you need to use webcals rather than webcal